# How can I access one of my note, in evernote, for personal use using developer token

Tags: evernote

I have an evernote account and I want to write a small application for my personal use. The application will read from the note, use the contents to take some decisions for me and may write back to it as well.

Its perfectly okay if the access is limited to one notebook, or just one note for now. I'm okay to make the note public for now, but I would prefer to keep to private.

For my specific use case, sandbox server won't be of much use. I can go directly to production as it will be a small script only. I have got a developer token but it seems that I can't really read note contents using it. Not sure, if oAuth token is the way to go since I'm not going to share this script publicly.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I think that is fine, just be careful not to share the developer token with anyone.  I do the same thing for small personal projects that I don't intend to share.

Comment: Hi,
Can you share the reference that you used to set up oAuth?

I have submitted a request here https://dev.evernote.com/support/
Should they have any objection to activate my token?

Comment: The dev token is totally unrelated to oauth.  For that you'll need the secret key and app key, and then follow the oauth examples.  The dev token is essentially equivalent to what you'll get back after doing the oauth dance to authenticate the user.